# Google App Engine Custom Domain With SSL Gives 404 Error

Tags: ssl, dns, google-cloud-storage

I followed [Custom Domains With SSL](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/securing-custom-domains-with-ssl) and have all the DNS settings in place. The console at [App Engine Project Settings](https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/settings/domains?project=Proj_id) shows **Google-managed, auto-renewing** under *SSL Security*. I waited for 24 hours and Google managed certificates seem to be in place. However, when I access

> **mydomain.com** or **www.mydomain.com** (with or without HTTPS)

it shows 404 error (*The requested URL was not found on this server.*)

Going back to my original DNS mappings with root and CNAME entries, the domain works but I would like it to run on HTTPS. Please advise.

Comment: Do you see any related log entries in your app's stackdriver logs? https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer?project=Proj_id

Comment: Yes I do see 4 entries roughly around the time when I created domain mapping following the tutorial. They look like 
2018-01-21 18:32:47.165 PST App Engine CreateDomainMapping mydomain.com myemail.

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified - I mean related to the 404 errors.

Comment: No 404 related errors. Just 4 records with CreateDomainMapping for mydomain.com and www.domain.com.

Comment: The original CNAME record pointed to c.storage.googleapis.com (its IP address 216.58.194.208) works fine. But this new CNAME mapping points to ghs.googlehosted.com. So I don't know why it is not able to connect to files uploaded at https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/

Comment: Can you confirm if you are using App Engine or Google Cloud Storage to host your website? I mean, is it a static website hosted using [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website) or is it indeed an App Engine application? I mean it because of the `c.storage.googleapis.com` CNAME record you mentioned, which points to a bucket in Cloud Storage.

Comment: Yes. That's the tutorial I followed and it is a static website on Google Cloud storage. But I thought I could connect GAE with cloud storage bucket such that Google managed SSL would come into play. Did I misunderstand this? Are they mutually exclusive?

Comment: While I would still like to understand if it is even possible and that I understood it correctly, I ended up using firebase storage which was much easier to host a static website with HTTPS enabled. I uploaded all my files to firebase using their command-line SDK and Firebase provided me with new set of "A" type DNS entries. An hour later, I had the same website up and running on HTTPS.

Comment: Just to add, the project is shared between Firebase and Google cloud. So I can actually see the traffic on both. I deleted all the files from Google cloud bucket and I thought I would delete the project as well but It ended up deleting the project from Firebase as well. I restored the project but not files on Google cloud. Files are now present only Firebase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The steps you reproduced are appropriate when trying to set up HTTPS connections for App Engine, but in fact you have a static website being hosted in Cloud Storage, as detailed in this [documentation tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website).

As noted there, in order to learn how to serve content using HTTPS, you will have to refer to [this other page](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/static-website#https). In short, these are the options you have available:

- Using the direct public URI for your website, as in `https://storage.googleapis.com/<YOUR_BUCKET>/<YOUR_WEBSITE>`. It is served using HTTPS by default.
- Cloud Storage does not currently support HTTPS serving when using a CNAME (which is the case if your custom domain is pointing to the website hosted in your bucket). In that case, you have three options:

  - Set up a **Load Balancer**, following [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/adding-a-backend-bucket-to-content-based-load-balancing).
  - Use **CDN Interconnect** (details [here](https://cloud.google.com/interconnect/docs/how-to/cdn-interconnect)) to serve your Cloud Storage content through a third-party Content Delivery Network.
  - Serve your website from **Firebase Hosting**, as detailed in this Firebase [getting started guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/deploying). This is the option I see you finally chose, as per the comments you posted on your original question.

Comment: Yes. I went through all that and setting up load balancer and proxies is beyond the scope of what I wanted to do. And as I mentioned in the comment above, I ended up using Firebase which provides a free certificate as well. Anyway, for closure I am accepting your answer.